# JSON call url to fetch data

Tags: php, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I am having problem while fetching data from the site, I want its dat to my site
http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-feeds-form.php

Here is the code
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>json data</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo" id="demo">
    <!-- <iframe src="http://www.cvedetails.com/widget.php?numrows=10&vendor_id=0&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opfileinc=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=1&cvssscoremin=10" width="100%" height="300px"></iframe> -->
</div>
<div class="demo2" id="demo2"><p></p></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var FEED_URL='http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=10&vendor_id=0&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opfileinc=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=1&cvssscoremin=10';

$.ajax({
  url      :  FEED_URL + encodeURIComponent(FEED_URL),
  dataType : 'json',
  success  : function (data) {
    if (data.responseData.feed && data.responseData.feed.entries) {
      $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (i, e) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.cvedetails.com');
        alert('e.title');
        $('#demo2').append($('<p/>').text(e.title));

        console.log("------------------------");
        console.log("title      : " + e.title);
        console.log("author     : " + e.author);
        console.log("description: " + e.description);
      });
    }
  }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwse9.png)

Comment: why `FEED_URL + encodeURIComponent(FEED_URL)` why not just `FEED_URL`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like that site doesn't support CORS since they don't set the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Since you can't fix this client side (outside of hacks), best is to set up a proxy server that can proxy the calls to that API. The proxy server can be on your own domain or you can specify the your own CORS response headers. You could also look into JSONP.

A guide on CORS: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/